# Не работает слайдшоу на joomla 3

Tags: jquery, javascript

Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста. У меня такая проблема, создаю сайт на joomla 2.5, в шаблонах от роккетов есть компонент rokgallery. Все работает отлично, но после обновления на joomla 3 не могу создать галерею! Пробовал на других компах, на одном работает, на другом нет. При создании галереи на joomla 3 сам менеджер оборванный почему-то, снизу нет кнопок save и close.

Comment: @Николай Мухтаров, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Николай Мухтаров, больше напишите о проблеме. Дело может быть в отсутствии определенных стилей, может быть, не подключены скрипты или "плагин" рассчитан на работу с определенной версией joomla, возможны и другие варианты.